# Swift split string to array with exclusion

Tags: swift

I write Swift application that parse log file.
log file string:

```
substr1 substr2 "substr 3" substr4
```

I need to get array: `[substr1, substr2, substr 3, substr4]`
But if I use something like:

```
print(stringLine.components(separatedBy: " "))
```

I got: `[substr1, substr2, "substr, 3", substr4]`.

How to receive array: `[substr1, substr2, substr 3, substr4]`?

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove `"` characters from the start and end of each string?

Comment: I have two types of substrings: 1) textSubsts, 2) "text substr" (include "") in the line. I need to split string into this two types of substring.

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible solutions is to use `map`:

```
    let testSting = "substr1 substr2 \"substr3\" substr4"

    let mappedString = testString.components(separatedBy: " ").map({$0.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")})

    print(mappedString) //["substr1", "substr2", "substr3", "substr4"]
```

This case of the issue is required to use regular expression but this example is provided. So to solve problem in you're case it is possible to go in this way:

```
var testStingArray  = testSting.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").components(separatedBy: " ")

var arr = [String]()

var step = 0

while step < testStingArray.count {
    var current = testStingArray[step]
    var next = step + 1
    if next < testStingArray.count {
        if testStingArray[next].characters.count == 1 {
            current += " " + testStingArray[next]
            testStingArray.remove(at: next)
        }
    }
    arr.append(current)
    step += 1
}

print(arr)//["substr1", "substr2", "substr 3", "substr4"]
```

Comment: I have: let testString = "substr1 substr2 \"substr 3\" substr4" (!!!! \"substr 3\" not \"substr3\") Useing your code, I receive: ["substr1", "substr2", "substr", "3", "substr4"]. But I need: ["substr1", "substr2", "substr 3", "substr4"]

Comment: Now `let testSting = "a b c d"` produces `["a b", "c d"]` – As soon as you remove the double quotes, information is lost and the result *cannot* be correct for all possible inputs.

Comment: @MartinR you are right with this statement. I take into account only the example that is provided by Sergey.

Answer (score 3):

You'd better work with regular expression:

```
let pattern = "([^\\s\"]+|\"[^\"]+\")"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])

let line = "substr1 substr2 \"substr 3\" substr4"

let arr = regex.matches(in: line, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<line.utf16.count))
    .map{(line as NSString).substring(with: $0.rangeAt(1)).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\""))}

print(arr) //->["substr1", "substr2", "substr 3", "substr4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could split the string based on a `CharacterSet` and then filter out the empty occurrences:

```
let stringLine = "substr1 substr2 \"substr3\" substr4"
let array = stringLine.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\" ")).filter { !$0.isEmpty }
print (array)
```

Output: `["substr1", "substr2", "substr3", "substr4"]`

But this will not work correctly if there is a `"` somewhere in one of the 'substrings', then that specific substring will also be split.

Comment: I have "substr 3\", but not "substr3\"

Comment: In that case, check @OOPer's answer and use regex. But be aware, writing your own CSV parsing can result in a world of hurt :) https://tburette.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/

Answer (score 0):

Or, simply iterate over the characters and maintain state about the quoted parts:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

extension String {

    func parse() -> [String] {

        let delimiter = Character(" ")
        let quote = Character("\"")

        var tokens = [String]()
        var pending = ""
        var isQuoted = false
        for character in self.characters {

            if character == quote {
                isQuoted = !isQuoted
            }
            else if character == delimiter && !isQuoted {
                tokens.append(pending)
                pending = ""
            }
            else {
                pending.append(character)
            }
        }

        // Add final token
        if !pending.isEmpty {
            tokens.append(pending)
        }

        return tokens
    }
}

print ("substr1 substr2 \"substr 3\" substr4".parse()) // ["substr1", "substr2", "substr 3", "substr4"]
print ("\"substr 1\" substr2 \"substr 3\" substr4".parse()) // ["substr 1", "substr2", "substr 3", "substr4"]
print ("a b c d".parse()) // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Note: this code doesn't take into account that double quotes `""` might be used to escape a single quote. But I don't know if that's a possibility in your case.

https://tburette.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/