# Remove quotation marks - Swift

Tags: swift, quotation-marks

From a .txt file I get strings that are full of quotation marks which of course are terrible to use in code. e.g.

```
 3820,"20170217",8,752,119,"Rh",,"fr",,,,"iC1.2","iC1.2",,"IS6a","Z",,0,"IS6a",,201702161517,"-"

 3821,"20170227",2,753,207,"Dd","Kru","sc",,,,"iB8","iB8",,"IS9b","Z",,2097152,"IS9b",,201702270804,"+~-"

 3822,"20170227",3,753,8,"Dd",,"phH_1",,,,"iB8",,,"IS12~IT12","Z",,2097153,"IS12~IT12",C,201702270804,"-"

 3823,"20170227",4,753,29,"Dd",,"phH_1",,,,"iB8",,,"IS11~IT11","Z",,2097153,"IS11~IT11",C,201702270804,"-"
```

How could I best get rid of these quotation marks??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give some context. Are you trying to paste the above into a Swift source file?

Comment: I'm trying to create  an array using all of these strings to later use in an analysis. But when placing it in an array, the quotation marks mess everything up.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487486/making-text-into-an-array-swift, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484311/swift-split-string-to-array-with-exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is CSV, so you'll need to parse it as CSV. There are several problems with your approach:

- The quotes mess everything up
- It's a mixture of strings and numbers - you won't be able to use an array
- There are consecutive commas, that would be illegal in an array literal.

The best approach is to put the data in a file (in your application bundle if you like) and find a CSV parser to read the data. My quick Google yielded [SwiftCSV](https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV) which looks reasonable, but I've never used it.